# how to trigger event on stopping a moving ball in corona sdk

Tags: coronasdk

I am trying to make a game in Corona which involves hitting the ball in a certain direction using the force vector. I am trying to trigger an event when the ball stops. I cannot use the "touch" event as the touch event is called several times when I touch the ball and set the direction for releasing it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Corona's custom events to dispatch your event when something occurs, in your case when the ball stops.  The code below will dispatch an event to the Runtime object.

```
local event = { name = "ballHasStoppedMoving", target = Runtime }
Runtime:dispatchEvent( event )
```

The following code would be used to listen for the "ballHasStoppedMoving" event and call your function "ballStoppedMoving" when the event fires.

```
local function ballStoppedMoving(event)

    print("The ball has stopped moving")

end

Runtime:addEventListener("ballHasStoppedMoving", ballStoppedMoving)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `phase` property of the [touch event](http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/events/touch), and only react on the "began" phase.

Answer (score 0):

In an enterFrame event, check for the velocity of the ball using ball.getLinearVelocity. If they do not equal (0,0), execute the method/event. If you want to execute a custom event at this time, follow Michael's answer.